# Swift Array to String

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

There is an array like:

```
 let datas =
    [["#A1CCE4","", "+0.0%", "+0.0%"],
     ["#4C3C2F","G", "+1.0%", "+0.2%"],
     ["#4C3C2F","G", "+3.1%", "+0.6%"],
     ["#C07155","S", "+0.3%", "+0.1%"],
     ["#C07155","G", "+2.0%", "+0.4%"],
     ["#C07155","P", "+1.8%", "+0.3%"],
     ["#AEB0B3","R", "+2.0%", "+2.0%"]]
```

How to convert it to string like:

```
"""let data = [["#A1CCE4", "", "+0.0%", "+0.0%"], ["#4C3C2F", "G", "+1.0%", "+0.2%"], ["#4C3C2F", "G", "+3.1%", "+0.6%"], ["#C07155", "S", "+0.3%", "+0.1%"], ["#C07155", "G", "+2.0%", "+0.4%"], ["#C07155", "P", "+1.8%", "+0.3%"], ["#AEB0B3", "R", "+2.0%", "+2.0%"]]"""
```

(with "let data = " or not is fine)

[image]

**EDIT**:

`"\(datas)"` should be the answer.

or

```
"\(String(describing: datas))"
```

or

```
datas.description
```

Why do I ask this question?

1. The array actually from the plist, and the number values are from different places.
2. The number values need to be load in the js code in `WKWebView`. And acutually the js code is just string.
3. In my js code I have actually the same code `datas` variable code.

Comment: I think that you have to manually create an algorithm, there's nothing built-in that produces that string as it's not a JSON

Comment: Why do you need this? May be there is any better approach.

Comment: @TheTiger I want this string actually is data which will be read in js code.

Comment: @WilliamHu Why don't you prefer a json string it will be easy to encode and decode on both sides?

Comment: Well, not necessarily. Actually, I want the WKWebview load js code just as a string like this. And the number values are from different places and saved to the plist.

Comment: @TheTiger I need conver it to JS code. If you downvoted this question, please check the edit. thanks.

Comment: @WilliamHu I don't downvote until I fully sure. I'm just trying to get your point.

Comment: @TheTiger all right, hopefully, you won't fully sure. thanks

Answer (score 5):

You actually want to create a JSON string, it's pretty easy with `JSONEncoder` because `[String]` conforms to `Encodable` by default.

```
let datas =
    [["#A1CCE4","", "+0.0%", "+0.0%"],
     ["#4C3C2F","G", "+1.0%", "+0.2%"],
     ["#4C3C2F","G", "+3.1%", "+0.6%"],
     ["#C07155","S", "+0.3%", "+0.1%"],
     ["#C07155","G", "+2.0%", "+0.4%"],
     ["#C07155","P", "+1.8%", "+0.3%"],
     ["#AEB0B3","R", "+2.0%", "+2.0%"]]

do {
    let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(datas)
    let result = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
    print(result)
} catch { print(error) }
```

It's more reliable than just calling `.description` on the array.
And only an array literal is directly interchangeable with JSON, a dictionary is not.

If you really need the `let datas =` prefix just concatenate the strings

```
let resultWithPrefix = "let datas = " + result
```

Comment: I answered the same but then realised the text he mentioned is not in json format. :|

Comment: @TheTiger The `let datas =` prefix doesn't seem to make sense because it's Swift specific syntax.

Comment: Thanks, acutally at first I tried `.description` but my XCode didn't auto-complete the method, I thought It's not possible. Any way, thanks for your answer : )

Comment: Both String Interpolation (`"\()"`) and `String(describing:)` APIs call `description`.

Comment: @vadian Yes you're right. One question `let str = "let datas = \(datas.description)"`  not a correct way?

Comment: @TheTiger It works, but both String Interpolation and calling `description` do exactly the same thing. Use only one of them, the other is redundant. Either `let str = "let datas = " + datas.description` or `let str = "let datas = \(datas)"`

Comment: I mean then why `JSONEncoder` is needed for this case.

Comment: @TheTiger It's not needed per se but it's the more robust solution. If the requirement changes and a dictionary is added `description` will break.

Comment: `["hey": "hola”].description` and `[["#A1CCE4","", "+0.0%", "+0.0%"],
             ["#4C3C2F":"+0.2%"]].description` also work.

Comment: Yes, of course it works, but the expected result for JavaScript/JSON is `{"hey": "hola”}` and `[["#A1CCE4","", "+0.0%", "+0.0%"], {"#4C3C2F":"+0.2%"}]`. In this case `JSONEncoder` encodes the stuff correctly.

Comment: Yes now got it. Thanks! (y)

Answer (score 2):

Given your `datas` array, you can achieve your goal this way:

```
let datas =
    [["#A1CCE4","", "+0.0%", "+0.0%"],
     ["#4C3C2F","G", "+1.0%", "+0.2%"],
     ["#4C3C2F","G", "+3.1%", "+0.6%"],
     ["#C07155","S", "+0.3%", "+0.1%"],
     ["#C07155","G", "+2.0%", "+0.4%"],
     ["#C07155","P", "+1.8%", "+0.3%"],
     ["#AEB0B3","R", "+2.0%", "+2.0%"]]
var str = " let datas = ["
for data in datas{
    str += "\(data)"
}
str += "]"
```

***EDIT:***

You can use this code, with a loop for each `String` array in your data, to get a string with comma

```
var str = " let datas = ["
for data in datas{

    str += "["
    for s in data{
        str += " \" \(s) \" ,  "
    }
    str += "],"
}
str += "]"
```

> Another good solution is to use `JSONEncoder`, as suggested in other answer, I just report it here to complete

```
let datas = [...]

var myString = "let datas ="

do{
  let datasToJson = JSONEncoder().encode(datas)
  myString += String(data: datasToJson, encoding: .utf8)! 
}catch{
   print(error)
}
```

Comment: You should print the comma as well according to his requirement

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
let stringStart = "let datas = "
let stringDatas = String(datas)
let finalString = stringStart + stringDatas
```

[More answers here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/strings/how-to-concatenate-strings-to-make-one-joined-string)